# How to customize deserialization of nested class in .Net

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Assume I have:

```
Class A
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
    string _label;
}
Class B
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
    string _label;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "class_a")]
    A _a;
}
Class C
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "label")]
    string _label;

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "class_b")]
    B _b;
}
```

I can serialize it to json and send it to server:

```
{
    label: "Label C"
    class_b: {
        label: "Label B"
        class_a: {
            label: "Label A"
        }
    }
}
```

However, the format I get from server is something like:

```
{
    label: "Label C"
    class_b: {
        label: "Label B"
        class_a: {
            label: [
                {
                    label0: "Label A"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

You can see label in class_a is changed to an array rather than a string, and I need to customize the conversion from json to Class A to convert the array back to string. So what's the best way to handle it?

I'm thinking about two ways:

1)
Implement a static method To* in each class:

```
class A {
    public static A ToA(JToken token) {
        label = token["label"][0]["label0"];
    }
}
class B {
    public static ToB(JToken token) {
        label = token["label"];
        _a = A.ToA(token["class_a"]);
    }
}
class C {
    public static ToC(Joken token) {
        label = token["label"];
        _b = B.ToB(token["class_b"])
    }
}
```

2)
Implement a customized JsonConverter and override ReadJson function:

```
public class CustomizedJsonConverter : JsonConverter {
    // This should do the normal converstion for class B and C, but customized convertion for class A
    override ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {}
}
```

Question:
1) Does method1 sound reasonable?
2) I need some guidance on method2, since I don't know how to handle it when it comes to nested class

Comment: I recently just ran into an issue with Newtonsoft that when deserializing the object it was adding an item to the array.  I don't know why... I know the classes were nested and I verified the Serializing json was good, wrote code to immediately deserialize it, scoped it out, and it was indeed modifying the array for some reason.  My thoughts are to work as small as possible as I've had a great experience with Newtonsoft until this one time.  It seems it has an issue with nested arrays and classes.  As far as using a token you don't have to.  JsonConvert has an overload to include the types.

Comment: @user2188649, could it be you're changing the serialized object on the server and thus get this result? I made [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p3Sohc) simple snippet to see if I understand you correctly - As you can see, it outputs your desired result. Is that what you need?

Comment: @HeyJude, the issue is that the server changes the format of Class A, thus the deserialization doesn't work if it refers to the definition of Class A.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII, thanks Michael, it's nice to know that.